# How to remove UIViewController from parent view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

When i click UIButton , i am using below code to show another UIViewController as overlay

```
        self.viewObj= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"list"];
        self.viewObj.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
        self.viewObj.view.layer.opacity=0.95;
        [self.view addSubview:self.viewObj.view];
        [self addChildViewController:self.viewObj];
```

This is working good, but now how to remove the new `UIViewController` from parent view ?

I tried below code and its not working

```
  self.viewObj= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"list"];
    [self.viewObj removeFromParentViewController];
```

Please help

UPDATE
In new viewcontroller

```
 ParentViewController *upObj=[[ParentViewController alloc]init];
 [upObj removePage];
```

in ParentViewController  , `removePage()` i have following code

```
[self.viewObj removeFromParentViewController];
```

Comment: Don't do `self.viewObj = ...` before you remove it

Comment: ok, then what should i do?

Comment: The same thing you have just without that line

Comment: when you want to remove do you only write ` [self.viewObj removeFromParentViewController];` directly without creating the object?

Comment: am calling a method from another class, inside that method i have written code to get remove

Comment: than it will be better if you get that view controller from heirarchy instead of creating new object

Comment: So your two code snippets aren't in the same class?

Comment: same class, but remove call is coming from another class

Comment: How are you calling that code from the other class?

Comment: updated my code with that part

Comment: ParentViewController *upObj=[[ParentViewController alloc]init];
 [upObj removePage];

Comment: It doesn't work because you're creating a new `ParentViewController` that isn't the one on-screen and removing that one's child.  You need to access the one that is in the hierarchy and call `removePage` on that.

Comment: can u tell me how do i do with code samples

Comment: I don't think you can call `removeFromParentViewController` unless you first called `addChildViewController`.  

Plus, like @dan mentioned, your `ParentViewController` is not the one that created `viewObj` so it can't dismiss it.

Comment: i got the solution, iam using notifications now